# Reference one document from another (SQL-style join) with NeDB

Tags: node.js, database, nedb

I have a bunch of documents in NeDB, let's say of the form:

```
{ _id : "3HDl4vDjQhcWvM76", type : "customer", name : "Bob" },
{ _id : "65byNNj7578B9hyu", type : "action", customer : "3HDl4vDjQhcWvM76", ... },
```

(So an 'action' references a 'customer')

And I want to do something like list all actions along with their customer names. The obvious way to do this would be:

```
db.find({ type: 'action' }, function (err, actions) {
  actions.forEach(function(action) {
    db.findOne({ type: 'customer', _id : action.customer }, function (err, customer) {
      console.log(action, customer.name);
    });
  });
 });
```

But that gets painful quite quickly. Is there a better way of doing this? Something like:

```
db.find({ type: 'action' }, {join : ["customer"]}, function (err, actions) {
  console.log(action, action.customer.name); 
});
```

would be awesome.

It seems like a really common thing to want to do, but I can't seem to find any information on doing it.

Thanks!

Comment: did you find something about your issue?

Comment: No... I just did as in the code above - with two distinct calls...

Comment: This is where NeDB breaks down and you realize, you won't be able to keep developing complex features with the simplicity of not relying on a  database server running somewhere :(